# Access Shipping rates meta data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to display the name of the box selected by my shipping method, in this case I am using this plugin for shipping over USPS:
USPS powered by Woocommerce Services and Jetpack (https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-services/)

I want to show the name of the cardboard box selected by the shipping method on my cart-totals.php, almost like the debug that my shipping plugin does but without having to enable the debug, I want to do this to make some sort of quote system, I was able to pull the weights but I haven't had the same luck with the packaging names since they seem to be stored in an array and right now I don't have the necessary knowledge to pull that one but I'll get there!

So far thanks to @LoicTheAztec I was able to pull the raw data from the array using his suggested code:

```
// The chosen shipping method (string) - Output the Shipping method rate ID
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];

// The array of shipping methods enabled for the current shipping zone:
$shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'];

// Loop through the array
foreach ( $shipping_methods as $method_id => $shipping_rate ){
 echo $shipping_rate->id . '<br>'; // combination of method_id + instance_id
 echo $shipping_rate->method_id . '<br>'; // shipping method slug (string)
 echo $shipping_rate->instance_id . '<br>'; // Numerical ID (string)
 echo $shipping_rate->label . '<br>'; // Label name (string)
 echo $shipping_rate->cost . '<br>'; // Cost (string)
 echo $shipping_rate->taxes . '<br>'; // Cost taxes (array)
}

// OR output the raw data array (test)
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $shipping_methods ); echo '</pre>';
```

I had to use output for the raw data because the previous loop wouldn't show the package name but it is there on the raw data, the raw data is the following:

```
Array
(
    [wc_services_usps:9:first_class_intl] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => wc_services_usps:9:first_class_intl
                [method_id] => wc_services_usps
                [instance_id] => 9
                [label] => First-Class Package International Service
                [cost] => 25.25
                [taxes] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [meta_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [wc_connect_packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [box_id] => 14x10x6
                                [length] => 14.5
                                [width] => 10.5
                                [height] => 6.75
                                [weight] => 2.565
                                [items] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 730
                                                [length] => 1.5
                                                [width] => 1.5
                                                [height] => 4.5
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 693
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 3.5
                                                [height] => 3.25
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [5] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [6] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 522
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 2.28
                                                [height] => 7.75
                                                [weight] => 0.135
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                                [id] => weight_0_14x10x6
                                [service_id] => first_class_intl
                            )

                    )

                [Packaging] => 14x10x6 
            )

    )

[wc_services_usps:9:pri_intl] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => wc_services_usps:9:pri_intl
                [method_id] => wc_services_usps
                [instance_id] => 9
                [label] => Priority Mail International
                [cost] => 42.10
                [taxes] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [meta_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [wc_connect_packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [box_id] => 14x10x6
                                [length] => 14.5
                                [width] => 10.5
                                [height] => 6.75
                                [weight] => 2.565
                                [items] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 730
                                                [length] => 1.5
                                                [width] => 1.5
                                                [height] => 4.5
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 693
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 3.5
                                                [height] => 3.25
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [5] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [6] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 522
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 2.28
                                                [height] => 7.75
                                                [weight] => 0.135
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                                [id] => weight_0_14x10x6
                                [service_id] => pri_intl
                            )

                    )

                [Packaging] => 14x10x6 
            )

    )

[wc_services_usps:9:pri_exp_intl] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => wc_services_usps:9:pri_exp_intl
                [method_id] => wc_services_usps
                [instance_id] => 9
                [label] => Priority Mail Express International
                [cost] => 56.35
                [taxes] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [meta_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [wc_connect_packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [box_id] => 14x10x6
                                [length] => 14.5
                                [width] => 10.5
                                [height] => 6.75
                                [weight] => 2.565
                                [items] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 730
                                                [length] => 1.5
                                                [width] => 1.5
                                                [height] => 4.5
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 693
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 3.5
                                                [height] => 3.25
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [5] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [6] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 522
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 2.28
                                                [height] => 7.75
                                                [weight] => 0.135
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                                [id] => weight_0_14x10x6
                                [service_id] => pri_exp_intl
                            )

                    )

                [Packaging] => 14x10x6 
            )

    )

[wc_services_usps:9:pri_intl_lg_box] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
    (
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [id] => wc_services_usps:9:pri_intl_lg_box
                [method_id] => wc_services_usps
                [instance_id] => 9
                [label] => Flat Rate: Priority Mail International
                [cost] => 62.35
                [taxes] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [meta_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [wc_connect_packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [box_id] => large_flat_box
                                [length] => 12
                                [width] => 12
                                [height] => 5.5
                                [weight] => 1.895
                                [items] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 730
                                                [length] => 1.5
                                                [width] => 1.5
                                                [height] => 4.5
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 756
                                                [length] => 1.76
                                                [width] => 1.76
                                                [height] => 3.75
                                                [weight] => 0.22
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 693
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 3.5
                                                [height] => 3.25
                                                [weight] => 0.28
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [4] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [5] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 685
                                                [length] => 2.75
                                                [width] => 2.75
                                                [height] => 5.25
                                                [weight] => 0.38
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                        [6] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [product_id] => 522
                                                [length] => 3.25
                                                [width] => 2.28
                                                [height] => 7.75
                                                [weight] => 0.135
                                                [quantity] => 1
                                            )

                                    )

                                [id] => flat-priority_international_0_large_flat_box
                                [service_id] => pri_intl_lg_box
                            )

                    )

                [Packaging] => Large Flat Rate Box 
            )

    )

)
```

At the end I just want to show the content of the [box_id] for each one of them, in this case I want to just show the "14x10x6":

```
            [meta_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [wc_connect_packages] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [box_id] => 14x10x6
                                [length] => 14.5
                                [width] => 10.5
                                [height] => 6.75
                                [weight] => 2.565
                                [items] => Array
```

Comment: "Woocommerce Services" doesn't mean anything if you don't add the link of the plugin, explain all related details and settings of your config… Remember that your shipping config is very specific and nobody can guess, visualize or reproduce the related data that should be included somewhere… This question is just unclear and unsolvable for the community…

Comment: Well, the code that you gave me was working and I was able to see the full array, and the information that I wanted was there in that array, what I didn't know and still don't know was how to pull it. Thank you anyway and I apologize for not making my question clear enough.

Comment: My answer will never answer this kind of question completely, as I can't reproduce your config… My answer was intended to help you to find the data *(that has been effective)* and in that case this answer was good and helpful and should have been accepted by you… Now you can edit your question adding the raw data output that you get and explain what you need to get… this way I could help you… But this need to be clear, with enough details…

Comment: It has been edited, once again I apologize for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead try:

```
// The chosen shipping method (string) - Output the Shipping method rate ID
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];

// The array of shipping methods enabled for the current shipping zone:
$shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'];

// Loop through the array
foreach ( $shipping_methods as $method_id => $shipping_rate ){
    $rate_id        = $shipping_rate->id;
    $method_id      = echo $shipping_rate->method_id;
    $instance_id    = echo $shipping_rate->instance_id;
    $label          = echo $shipping_rate->label;
    $cost           = $shipping_rate->cost;
    $taxes          = $shipping_rate->taxes;

    // Get the meta data in an unprotected array
    $meta_data = $shipping_rate->get_meta_data();

    ## ----- BELOW the data you are looking for ----- ##

    $connect_packages = $meta_data['wc_connect_packages'][0];

    $box_id = $connect_packages->box_id; // (string)
    $length = $connect_packages->length; // (float)
    $width  = $connect_packages->width;  // (float)
    $height = $connect_packages->height; // (float)
    $weight = $connect_packages->weight; // (float)
    $items  = $connect_packages->items;  // (array of object)
}

// OR output the raw data array (test)
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $shipping_methods ); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I get the information about each shipment but not the name of the box which is the only thing I want, I got the full array with the test echo and I was able to pinpoint it
    foreach  ( $shipping_methods->wc_connect_packages as $box_id => $shipping_rate ){
     echo $shipping_rate->box_id . '<br>'; // shipping method slug (string)

}

Comment: @DanielMonsalve As it seem that you are using some additional shipping plugin or something that is not by default in Woocommerce, I snot possible to help you if you don't clearly explained it in details in the question itself… **My code just show you the way to understand and get the available shipping data that is stored in Woocommerce sessions**… Nobody in stackOverFlow can guess about your custom shipping boxes or whatever

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec, I said on my main question that I am using "Woocommerce Services" as a shipping method. "Woocommerce Services" is in fact a plugin for Woocommerce that connects itself to Jetpack to get live USPS shipping rates, labels and tax calculations.

Comment: @Daniel Ok this time you get the way and the data

Comment: Awesome thanks!! now it works!, I just had to remove one extra closing parenthesis and add some semicolons and voila!

Comment: @Daniel … I have some dust on my glasses and in my mind may be too… Thanks for the edit :)